# Access object property within a callback

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code:

```
var Request = require('./request');

function Treasure(id) {
    Treasure.prototype.valid = false;
    Treasure.prototype.id = id;
    Treasure.prototype.contentLength = 0;
    Treasure.prototype.title = null;
    Treasure.prototype.seller = null;
    Treasure.prototype.buyer = null;
    Treasure.prototype.cost = 0;
}

Treasure.prototype.loadData = function() {
    EpvpRequest.treasureRequest(Treasure.prototype.id, function(data) {
        if (data.valid) {
            Treasure.prototype.valid = data.valid;
            Treasure.prototype.contentLength = data.contentLength;
            Treasure.prototype.title = data.title;
            Treasure.prototype.seller = data.seller;
            Treasure.prototype.buyer = data.buyer;
            Treasure.prototype.cost = data.cost;
        }
    });
}

module.exports = Treasure;
```

Please don't hit me, I just started learning javascript.
I want ot access the properties of "Treasure"; but I can't use `this`, because I have a callback in the loadData function and `this` would refer to the function which called the callback - is that correct?

But it seems that I can't access the properties the way I tried with `Treasure.prototype.property`.

What is the correct way to to this?

Comment: *"and this would refer to the function which called the callback - is that correct?"* No. `this` almost never refers to a function.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should be assigning instance variables in the constructor instead of assiginng to the prototype. The prototype is for methods and other things that will be shared by all Treasure instances.

```
function Treasure(id) {
    this.valid = false;
    this.id = id;
    this.contentLength = 0;
    this.title = null;
    this.seller = null;
    this.buyer = null;
    this.cost = 0;
}
```

As for your problem with `this` inside callbacks, the usual workaround is to store the value of `this` in a regular variable and then use that variable inside the callback.

```
Treasure.prototype.loadData = function() {
    // Nothing special about "that"
    // Its just a regular variable.
    var that = this;
    EpvpRequest.treasureRequest(that.id, function(data) {
        if (data.valid) {
            that.valid = data.valid;
            that.contentLength = data.contentLength;
            that.title = data.title;
            that.seller = data.seller;
            that.buyer = data.buyer;
            that.cost = data.cost;
        }
    });
}
```

Since this pattern comes up very often, some people choose to always use the same name for the "this-storage" variable. Some of the more popular names are `self` and `that`.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that. Thank you very much.